# Attach Event Handler ".on()" on dynamic button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `button` which is dynamically added on the page (via mustache).

There is a class on it.

But when I click on this button, the `JQuery` method is not executed.

My HTML:

```
<div id="layout"></div>
```

My HTML with the dynamically added button:

```
<div id="layout">
    <a href="#" class="hello">Hello</a>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.hello').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Hello');
    });
});
```

Comment: put the code that creates the button and i will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `on()` on elements that dont exist, asign them to the first wrapper that exists (ideally an id), and use another parameter to tell jQuery to look for the class in the selector:

```
$('#layout').on('click', '.hello', function(e){ /* ... */ });
```

**"Can't I just add everything to document?"**
Yes you could, but you shouldn't. Everytime you click on something, it goes up the DOMtree:
 1. You click a button, it fires the click event
 2. while there is a parent, trigger the click event for the parent aswell
 3. After you did the last (document), stop.

As you can see, step 2 could be a heavy step if you have lots of html. Binding events as 'local' as possible is the prefered method.